# Css Centering without affecting each side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple NavBar using Twitter Bootstrap and Rails 3.2

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-inner">
 <div class="container">
  <%= link_to logo, root_path, :class=>"logo1" %>
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
   <% if signed_in? %>
    <li class="hova"><%= link_to "#" %></li>
    <li class="hova"><%= link_to "#" %></li>
    <li class="hova"><%= link_to "#" %></li>
    <li class="hova"><%= link_to "#" %></li>
    <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-user"></i><b class="caret"></b>
     </a>
```

```
 </header>
```

As of now, the logo sits on the left of the centered toolbar and the links and dropdown caret sit on the right with no spacing from each side.

How could I add some padding/ margin to both (move the logo about 5px to the left, and the right content about 5 px to the right so I sacrifice center whitespace instead of moving the contents.

For example,

```
.navbar .container {
 width: 960px;
 margin-left:10px;
 }
```

..works for the left side. But how could I achieve the same for the right at the same time? Apologies, not much of a front end designer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the logo in a span

```
<span class="logo"><%= link_to logo, root_path, :class=>"logo1" %></span>
```

Then use CSS as -

```
.logo{
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}

.dropdown{
    margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: .logo{ margin: 0 0 0 5px; } & .dropdown{ margin: 0 5px 0 0; } actually worked. I think cause I have them floated left and right. Thanks Diparks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img src="logo.png" style="margin-left:-5px;" />
```

Comment: Thank you Rizwanabbasi...I'm using Embedded Ruby so adding a class to it was much easier, but thanks anyways!